# How can I find python facebook graph api connection_name?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am using python facebook graph api and after obtaining my access_token, I do the following:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(response['access_token'])
user = graph.get_object("me")
```

Then I tried to call:

```
graph.get_connections(self, id, connection_name, **args)
```

but I have no idea where to find connection_name and in the library example, I can only find "friends" used to get a list of your friend name.

Comment: Could you point to the python library you're using and the example you are referencing? A simple link would do

Comment: Sure. [link](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what **Reference** that are going to be accessed. For example for **Page**, look at the "**Edges**" table in the following URL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/